# Изменять значение ячейки по ID BitArray

Tags: c#, .net

Я создаю BitArray

```
byte[] myBytes = new byte[5] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
BitArray myBA = new BitArray(myBytes);



False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
```

Каким образом можно изменять значения по Id ячейки при необходимости, например 4, 22 ячейку на true(если считать сверху)?

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно что вы имели ввиду под "4, 22 ячейку", но вообще это обычный массив каждый элемент которого - бит...инициализация этого массива для простоты сделана через массивы разных типов, в вашем случае создается массив из 5*8(кол-во битов в байте)=40 элементов(бит).

Согласно документации читать и писать определенный бит можно используя простой индексатор

```
myBA[32]=True
```